# Display images layer by layer in ImageView not works

Tags: android, android-imageview, layer, layerdrawable

In my application I have a set of drawbles. I have to show it as layer by layer. For that I am using LayerDrawble.  I have used it in this way

```
ImageView

     image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);                

        Resources r = getResources();
        Drawable[] capas = new Drawable[3];

        capas[0] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
        capas[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon2);
        capas[2] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon3);           

        LayerDrawable capasDrawable = new LayerDrawable(capas);
        image.setImageDrawable(capasDrawable);
```

But it displays the top most image only. That means it not shows the whole 3 images layer by layer.

How do i display it as layet by layer

**Update**
I need a view like this, the first and last images aligned in layers.

[image: in this image it shows multiples layers]

I have done aa jason posted in answer. The image shows layer by layer. But its bottom part has some weird look.. See the screen shot. And how do i make it correct  [image]

Comment: A LayerDrawable is an array of Drawables. When you call setImageDrawalbe it will only show the last one (largest index). What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please reload the question. I have uploaded a demo image, i need a view like in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to use setLayerInset.

setLayerInset(layer, leftOffset, topOffset, rightOffset, bottomOffset)

I'm not sure about the positioning, you'll have to tweak that.

```
    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);                

    Resources r = getResources();
    Drawable[] capas = new Drawable[3];

    capas[0] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
    capas[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon2);
    capas[2] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon3);           

    LayerDrawable capasDrawable = new LayerDrawable(capas);

    // Set bottom layer inset
    capasDrawable.setLayerInset(0, 5, 0, 0, 5);

    // Set middle layer inset
    capasDrawable.setLayerInset(1, 10, 0, 0, 10);

    // Set top layer inset
    capasDrawable.setLayerInset(2, 15, 0, 0, 15);

    image.setImageDrawable(capasDrawable);
```